# python while loop didn't append any values into to the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/ymx19/Desktop/EHS/Location/results/Batch3_enterprise_with_missing_level/HOU.csv',header = 0)
df = df.dropna(axis ='columns',how ='all')
headers_list = [x for x in df.columns]
count = len(headers_list)
k = headers_list[-1]
maxlevel = df[df[k].notna()].drop_duplicates(subset= headers_list, keep="last")
while count > 3:
    m = headers_list[-1]
    headers_list.pop()
    z = headers_list[-1]
    lower_level = df.drop_duplicates(subset=headers_list, keep="last")
    lower_level = lower_level[lower_level[z].notna() & lower_level[m].isna()]
    maxlevel.append(lower_level)
    count -= 1 
maxlevel.to_csv('C:\\Users\\ymx19\\Desktop/EHS\\Location\\results\\test\\HOU.csv', index = False)
```

Question:
The the final maxlevel.csv didn't include any appended values from the while loop

Comment: Append is not an inplace operation you must assign back to update the dataframe: `maxlevel = maxlevel.append(lower_level)`

Comment: Thanks Henry!! It helps a lot !